# CoreMotion [ViewController updateReferenceAttitude:] - why is the selector not recognised?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-motion, target-action

I’m new to `CoreMotion`. My first program shows `deviceManager` changing values for pitch, roll and yaw but crashes when it tries to set `referenceAttitude`

```
    - (void)updateReferenceAttitude
    {
        self.refAttitude = self.manager.deviceMotion.attitude;
        NSLog(@"you clicked a button that took a 3D snapshot");
    }
```

In debug, the statement in my method

```
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(updateReferenceAttitude:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

crashes with the following

```
    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController updateReferenceAttitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14875a00'
```

To test it, I use Xcode 8.3.3 with an iPhone 5 C running iOS 10.3.3.

Can anyone explain why this `selector` is not recognised ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed and had little to do with `CoreMotion`. The method

```
- (void)updateReferenceAttitude
```

should be

```
- (void)updateReferenceAttitude:(UIButton *(sender
```

I had included a `UIButton` to reset the reference attitude while the app is running but was calling the same method automatically after `ViewDidLoad` launches.

The problem was solved by using a statement for the initial reference instead of calling the method.

```
    if (self.refAttitude == nil)
    {
        self.refAttitude = self.manager.deviceMotion.attitude;  // initial run
        //        [self updateReferenceAttitude];
    }
```